# How to show loading screen at start of function in kivymd?

Tags: python, kivy, python-3.8, kivymd

I want to use loading screen in my Kivymd app during getting data from web. But when I run my code, loading screen appears after getting data.

I want to show loading screen, get some data from web, then display result on new screen.
This is part of my `get_data` function. This function run when user click button.

```
def get_data(self):
    self.root.ids.MainScreen.pos_hint = {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 50} # Hide main screen
    self.root.ids.LoadingScreen.pos_hint = {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5} # Show loading screen
    requests.get("https//.....")
    # Code more
```

It takes almost ten seconds for loading. I put screen move code in top of my function, but why screen move code run after function? How to solve this?

I'm using Windows 10 and Python 3.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `threading` or `Clock.schedule` to move to loading screen before all the request work is done. Check more details [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html)

```
def get_data(self):
    self.root.ids.MainScreen.pos_hint = {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 50} # Hide main screen
    self.root.ids.LoadingScreen.pos_hint = {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5} # Show load screen
    Clock.schedule_once(function_to_get_data)
def function_to_get_data(self, *args):
    #code to get data
```

**UPDATE:**
Here's code for threading with parameter:

```
def get_data(self):
    self.root.ids.MainScreen.pos_hint = {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 50} # Hide main screen
    self.root.ids.LoadingScreen.pos_hint = {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5} # Show load screen
    threading.Thread(target = function_to_get_data, args=(param,))
def function_to_get_data(self, param):
    #code to get data
```

Comment: This seems work, but what if I want to pass parameter to `function_to_get_data`? I think I can't use parameter in `Clock.schedule_once(function_to_get_data)`

Comment: [This](https://imgur.com/5oIcJzP) is calling part, and [this](https://imgur.com/7ey93Pa) is get_data part. (I don't know how to insert multiline code in Stack Overflow comment.) But when I run this code, it gives me [this](https://imgur.com/undefined) errors and `TypeError: get_data() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. How to solve this?

Comment: If you want to pass some data then what you can do is create a class variable then access that class variable in clock function or you can use threading. Threading will do the same thing and can also take variable.

Comment: And about the error, Clock.schedule_once also gives the time after which it was executed as an argument. I forgot about that sorry for that, I have updated the code

Answer (score 2):

You could use a window manager. Hard to say without your complete code but something like:

```
    from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
    from kivy.core.window import Window
    
class MainScreen(Screen):
...
    def get_data(self):
        self.parent.current = 'LoadingWindow'
        get your data
        wait for it to return
        self.parent.current = 'MainWindow'
...
class LoadingScreen(Screen):
    pass
...
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass
```

This assumes a.o. get_data is in the MainScreen Class and LoadingScreen and MainScreen are defined as screens in a window manager like so (in .kv)

```
WindowManager:
    LoadingScreen:
    MainScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    id: mainWindow
    ...

<LoadingScreen>:
    id: LoadingWindow
    ...
```

Comment: This example is running the code but not able to display the loading screen, its just waiting for the wait process to complete and directly going to the "MainScreen" without displaying the loading screen